# Aggregate and find match

Tags: r, dplyr

How to use dplyr after grouping the column A so that if one among them eg: 'a1'  contains `A22 or R22` it have to say `Yes` for all 'a1' else `No` in a new column C.

Please help me to achieve this.

Dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A= c("a1","a1","a1","b1","b1","b1","c1","c1"),
                  B= c("A22","B2","C2","R22","G2","C2","G2","O2"))
```

```
A           B            
a1         A22
a1         B2
a1         C2
b1         R22
b1         G2
b1         C2
c1         G2
c1         O2
```

Expected Result:

```
A           B       C
a1         A22      Yes
a1         B2       Yes
a1         C2       Yes 
b1         R22      Yes
b1         G2       Yes
b1         C2       Yes
c1         G2       No
c1         O2       No
```

Comment: Can you try on a fresh session as I can't reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'A', then if `any` of the strings 'A22', 'R22' are there `in%` 'B' to create the 'Yes', 'No' values in 'C'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(C = c("No", "Yes")[1+ (any(c("A22", "R22") %in% B))])
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   A [3]
#  A     B     C    
#  <fct> <fct> <chr>
#1 a1    A22   Yes  
#2 a1    B2    Yes  
#3 a1    C2    Yes  
#4 b1    R22   Yes  
#5 b1    G2    Yes  
#6 b1    C2    Yes  
#7 c1    G2    No   
#8 c1    O2    No
```

---

Or we can use `base R`

```
with(df1, ave(as.character(B), A, FUN = function(x) 
       c("No", "Yes")[1 + any(c("A22", "R22") %in% x)]))
#[1] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "No"  "No"
```

Comment: i m surprised, still i get that c1 as yes when i execute with the same dataframe ```df1 <- data.frame(A= c("a1","a1","a1","b1","b1","b1","c1","c1"),
                  B= c("A22","B2","C2","R22","G2","C2","G2","O2"))
```

Comment: @prog Sorry, I can't reproduce it

Comment: Thanks both worked after restarting. Could u tell me why restarting worked for me!

Comment: @prog It could be that you have accidentally named some objects  with a function identifier or some other envriorment related issue

Answer (score 2):

```r
df1 %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    mutate(C = factor(max(B %in% c("A22", "R22")),
                      levels = 0:1,
                      labels = c("No", "Yes"))) %>%
    ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   A     B     C    
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 a1    A22   Yes  
#> 2 a1    B2    Yes  
#> 3 a1    C2    Yes  
#> 4 b1    R22   Yes  
#> 5 b1    G2    Yes  
#> 6 b1    C2    Yes  
#> 7 c1    G2    No   
#> 8 c1    O2    No
```

Comment: when i execute even for c1 says 'yes' with the same dataframe. Cant understand why i get it different!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(
  A= c("a1","a1","a1","b1","b1","b1","c1","c1"),
 B= c("A22","B2","C2","R22","G2","C2","G2","O2"))

dt[, 
    flag := case_when(
      B %in% c("A22", "R22") ~ "Yes",
      TRUE ~ "No"
    )
]
dt[, flag := factor(flag, levels = c("No", "Yes"), ordered = TRUE)]

dt[, flag := max(flag), by = A]
```